Is it normal for my Nassarius Snail to be at the top of my tank?
Is it normal for my Nassarius snail to hang out at the top of its tank? When I purchased them I was told that they usually hang out in the sand unless is it feeding time.
Should I be worried about this behavior? Especially, if they stay at the top for extended periods of time?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.
